# Solve this inequality $10 > e^{-x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-verification, logarithms, exponential-function

Let $x$ be a real number

We want to derive the inequality relationship in terms of $x$ alone:

**Method 1:**
$$10> e^{-x} \implies \ln(10) > -x \implies \ln(10)^2 > x^2 \implies |\ln(10)| > x$$

**Method 2:**
$$10> e^{-x} \implies \ln(10) > -x \implies -\ln(10) < x $$

Which is correct?

Comment: Method 2 is correct.

Comment: Why did you square in method 1?  Why do you think a > b implies a^2 > b^2 if be can be negative?

Comment: 1 > -5,000 and $1^2 < (-5,000)^2$ so method 1 is right out.  a > b => a^2 > b^2 is only true if b >= 0.  If 0 >= a > b then a^2 < b^2.  And if a > 0 > b then a^2 > b^2 if |a| > |b|, or a^2 = b^2 if |a| = |b| or a^2 < b^2 if |a| < |b|.

Comment: whereas method 2 is just fine.

Comment: method 3 10 > e^-x =>  1/10 < e^x => ln (1/10) < x => - ln 10 < x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: $x>y$ does not imply $x^2>y^2$ (consider $x=1$ and $y=-1$).